# How to add a second conditional to CakePHP Auth Login?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to make a login page for my CakePHP website, and my user database is set up so that usernames are only unique within groups (i.e. Group 1 and Group 2 can both have a user named johndoe, but there can only be one johndoe per group).

Is there any way to set an extra conditional to the login routine so that it searches by both username and group when checking the validity of the login?

Thanks in advance! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably what you're looking for: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1268/userScope